# border on div won't show up in outlook

Tags: html, outlook

I'm desperately trying to get a border to show up around this div in Outlook.

Here's the HTML

```
<div id="footer" style="border: 3px solid #2B5387;"> 
        
<!--lots of html-->
</div>
```

Comment: Outlook? As in your are sending an email and outlook doesn't show it correctly?

Comment: Yes, im sending an html email

Comment: It's showing border just fine:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOzg3.png

This question does not belong here, unless you need help with code, which I don't see any evidence that you do.